# market links to google play in browser

Tags: google-play-store

I just bought a desire HD. I did the factory reset. When I click on Market (old app or at least old icon), it opens a new window in the browser with the policy of google play. At the moment I click, I see the accept and decline buttons shortly but can't click on them, they then disappear.

Basically I can't use market. There is no google play app on the phone either...

Does anyone else have this issue? Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: After trying several times I managed to click accept before the link opens. Then I had to accept google play terms and now I still have the old market app and logo but when I open it it seems to be new like google play... really weird...

Comment: So your problem is solved? Maybe you want to put your solution into an answer and accept it, so it can be helpful to others?

Answer (score 1):

I found if I went in and cleared the Market Data (from settings -> applications), it then let me accept the terms and then started the same browser.  The next time after that, that I clicked on Market, it took me to the proper interface.